# Compilation error while retrieving string at an index in a list

Tags: java, arrays, append

```
private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    strArray.remove(this.txtInputName.getText());
    String strBadSong = this.txtInputName.getText();
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.size()-1; i++){                        
        if (strBadSong.equals(strArray.get[i])){
            strArray.remove(this.txtInputName.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, this is Jeffrey and I'm having some trouble with my .append() method. The for statement goes through all the indexes for strArray and is suppose to see whether or not strBadSong == the song in the array, and if it is then remove it. I keep on getting an error with the .get part of the code. Could anyone help me out a bit here? I'm new to coding sorry!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `"I keep on getting an error with the .get part of the code."` -- the error messages are **very** important. In the future when asking similar questions, please show any and all *complete* error messages, as this will prevent our having to guess. As it is, you likely have a terrible typo error as per Vivin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `strArray.get(i)` instead of what you have, because it looks like `strArray` is actually `List<String>`; `get` is a method. If `strArray` was `String[]` you would use `strArray[i]`.

Also your `for` loop will miss the last element. You want the terminating condition to be `i < strArray.size()` and not `i < strArray.size() - 1`.